# How can i make a cross domain DELETE request from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am writing a piece of JavaScript that needs to call the Google Latitude API to delete a point.

The request to Google Latitude is of the form:

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/latitude/v1/location/locationId
```

Is there any way of doing this directly from Javascript, or do I have to make the request from the server side?

Comment: GET and POST are most well known CORS supported requests, but you might something useful for https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control Also here is a server-side proxy view written in Python which do CORS detection and proxy if it's not supported http://opensourcehacker.com/2011/08/02/ajax-proxy-view-with-python-urllib-and-plone/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible because of the browser's same origin policy.

With JavaScript you can put together GET requests with dynamically generated scripts tags and images or POST requests by submitting a form.